Using multiple tables for lookup in MySQL
I'm normally pretty good at finding the answer I need by searching, but I'm drawing a blank on this one.
Let's say I have two tables that both have a list of names and ID numbers (we'll call them a and b). There is some other data in each of these tables which is why they are different tables, but for this query all I need is the name. What I currently have is something along the lines of:
SELECT c.number, c.field, a.name FROM c LEFT JOIN a ON (c.number = a.number)

However, it's possible that the number I'm looking for is not in a but is instead in b. How can I retrieve a.name is my number is in table a but b.name if the number is in table b? The code that loads this data (and other policies about this number) ensures that it will only exist in one table or the other.

Try COALESCE().  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

well if you can have a record in A but not C and C but not A then a FULL OUTER Join is need in conjunction with the colesce()  but mySQL doesn't support it; so you'll have to do C LEFT JOIN A UNION A LEFT JOIN C

Are you saying there's 3 tables: C, A, and B and the name can be in A or B but never both?  If that's the case simply union A and B before you left join from C.  The question is a bit vague.  So sample data expected results would help describe the issue.

@xQbert - Correct. c is basically a log of events. The name will most likely be found in a but could be in b. There are actually two other lookup tables as well, but I left them out for simplicity. The answer from @ysth below to use a combination of COALESCE and a second LEFT JOIN worked perfectly.

Just join both:
select c.number, c.field, coalesce(a.name, b.name) name
from c
left join a on a.number = c.number
left join b on b.number = c.number

Some are suggesting you join a union instead:
select c.number, c.field, ab.name
from c
left join (
    select a.number, a.name from a
    union all
    select b.number, b.name from b
) ab on ab.number = c.number

but that is unlikely to perform well.

Thank-you. That first suggestion worked perfectly.

You can use COALESCE
SELECT c.number, c.field, COALESCE(a.name, c.name) AS name
FROM c 
FULL JOIN a ON c.number = a.number


MySQL doesn't support Full outer join, you'll need to union. from C LEFT join A UNION FROM A LEFT JOIN C  but i'm unsure if they mean A UNION B since the record is in A or B and C is the table they wan't to left join from...
